# My website URL changes automatically to HTTPS

Tags: php, http, https

I have a website developed in Core PHP. It is a shopping cart website and I used Stripe Payment Gateway for payment integration.

If the website is static for some time, the URL changes from HTTP to HTTPS.

I don't know where it is happening. Even in my localhost also I am getting the same.

Comment: What isn’t it https altogether in the first place? Also without code it’s hard to tell.

Comment: If you use the browser's F12 key, network tab, and preserve logs you can look at the navigation trace see exactly what navigation changes it.   It could be a normal navigation or a 3xx moved.